# Parsing JSON Data for Lazy Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-3.2, lazy-high-charts

I'm having some issues with parsing some JSON data into high charts using the Lazy Highcharts gem. I'm trying to select only the data from the last 7 days, or 1 week ago. At this stage my application just hangs and doesn't load with the code below.

I am loading the JSON data from a link.I have tried the pointStart option, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

JSON

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16 16:00:00": 24.2},{"2014-06-17 12:00:00": 30.2},{"2014-06-18 17:00:00": 42.9}]} etc
```

Controller

```
@data =  Oj.load(open(@temperature.url).read)

results = []

@data['data'].each do |data|
 results << ((7.day.ago.to_i * 1000)..(Date.today.to_i * 1000)).map { |date| [DateTime.parse(data.keys.first).to_i * 1000 == date, data.values.first] }
end 

@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart(:height => '400', width: '860')
  f.yAxis [:title => {:text => "Temperature, :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}]
  f.series(:type => 'line', :name => 'Temperature', pointStart: 7.day.ago.to_i * 1000, data: results, marker: {enabled: false}, :color => '#00463f' )
  f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', tickInterval: 1.day.to_i * 1000, :tickmarkPlacement => 'on', :startOnTick => true )
  f.legend({:align => 'center', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 0, :borderWidth => 0, style: {color: "#333"}})
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this. If any one is interested I added;

```
min: 1.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000
```

To the xAxis.